# PhantomJS Login and Page Redirect

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to crawl a website which kind of have a login page seperated and jumping homepage after login. Here is my code, but I am not accomplishment jumping homepage:

```
var page = require('webpage').create() ;
var login = 'https://webstie.com/login' ;
var home = 'https://website.com/home' ;

page.open(login, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('fail!');
    } else {
        page.evaluate(function(){
            function timer (f,n) {
                var i = 0 ;
                var t = setInterval(function(){
                    if (n < i) {
                        clearInterval(t) ;
                        f() ;
                    }
                    i++ ;
                },50) ;
            }
            $("input[name=email]").val("user") ;
            $("input[name=password]").val("pass") ;
            $("input[type=submit]").click() ;
            timer(function(){
                document.location.href = home ;
                timer(function(){
                    $('body').css('border','1px solid red') ;
                },100) ;
            },100) ;
        }) ;
        page.render('page.png') ;
    }
    console.log('finished!') ;
    phantom.exit() ;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to wait for asynchronous processing. Your `timer()` function is asynchronous, because `setTimeout()` is asynchronous. That is why your `page.render()` call happens actually before the `timer()` has run. The same goes for `phantom.exit()`.

But you don't want to use `document.location.href = home`, because then you need to listen to the page open event. You can do this in an integrated fashion with another `page.open()`.

Try:

```
page.open(login, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('fail!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        page.evaluate(function(){
            $("input[name=email]").val("user") ;
            $("input[name=password]").val("pass") ;
            $("input[type=submit]").click() ;
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            page.open(home, function(status){
                if (status !== "success") {
                    console.log('fail2');
                    phantom.exit(1);
                    return;
                }
                page.evaluate(function(){
                    $('body').css('border','1px solid red') ;
                });
                page.render('page.png');
                console.log('finished!');
                phantom.exit();
            });
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Use [`waitFor()`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) for more robust waiting for a specific condition or use the [`page.onCallback` and `window.callPhantom()` pair](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html).